# How to remove commas in columns in R

Tags: r

```
# Importing the required libraries
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

# Loading the csv file into the dataframe

#Need to properly solve the 11th line and show what was tried
data1=read_csv("covid_worldwide.csv",show_col_types=FALSE)
head(data1)
typeof(data1$'Total Cases')
data1$`Total Cases` <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data1$'Total Cases'))

#plot that line

ggplot(data=data1,
       aes(x=Total Cases))+
  geom_histogram()


#unique(data1$`Total Cases`)
```

I've tried unique(data1$`Total Cases`) but that was to no avail.

I'm not entirely sure what else to try here, any I'm getting errors with no understanding of the error...

Comment: Can you show `dput(head(data1))` for testing

Comment: What data is on the 11th line?

Comment: consider using `data[['Total Cases']]`

Comment: Also what are your errors?

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"ggplot(data=data1,
       aes(x=Total Cases"

Comment: R does not like variables with spaces in their name, in most of your code you are using ` or ' to wrap`'total cases'`, however in the `ggplot` code, you are not single quoting the x variable.